# Resizing numpy array from (32,32,3) to (224,224,3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, keras, rgb

I'm working with keras `cifar10` dataset, which gives me a set of RGB images as `numpy array` in the `shape (32,32,3)`.

I'm trying to resize that RGB image to (224,224,3), but every time I'm trying to do it with the `reshape function`:

```
test = x_train[0].reshape(224,224,3)
```

I am getting  following error:

> ERROR: cannot reshape array of size 3072 into shape (224,224,3)

Does anyone knows how to reshape the RGB images ?

Comment: Try to explain what you are trying to do conceptually. "Resize" can mean lots of things

Comment: Resizing != Reshaping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reshaping an array with shape (32,32,3) into an array with shape (224,224,3) cannot be done using np.reshape since it would require additional data to be created or existing data to be interpolated, which is not how np.reshape works.

If you want to resize an image, use OpenCV:

```
import cv2

test = cv2.resize(x_train[0], dsize=(224, 224), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
```